# SMT prover yields 'unknown' despite strong proven assertions

Tags: z3, verification, frama-c, alt-ergo

Suppose we have the following C annotated code:

```
#define L  3
int a[L] = {0};
/*@ requires \valid(a+(0..(L - 1)));
    ensures \forall int j; 0 <= j < L ==> (a[j] == j); */
int main() {
        int i = 0;
        /*@ loop assigns i, a[0..(i-1)];
            loop invariant inv1: 0 <= i <= L;
            loop invariant inv2:
                        \forall int k; 0 <= k < i ==> a[k] == k; 
        */
        while (i < L) {
          a[i] = i;
          i++;
        }
        /*@ assert final_progress:
               \forall int k; 0 < k < L ==> a[k] == a[k-1] + 1; 
            assert final_c: 
               a[2] == a[1] - 1; */
        return 0;
}
```

Why Alt-Ergo/Z3 yields "unknown" or timeouts for final_c assertion despite the fact that final_progress statement was proven? 
I would definitely like to see "Not valid" for such obviously (from user point of view) invalid statements.

```
$ frama-c -wp -wp-rte -wp-prover z3 test2.c
..
[wp] [z3] Goal typed_main_assert_final_c : Unknown (455ms)

$ frama-c -wp -wp-rte -wp-prover alt-ergo test2.c 
..
[wp] [Alt-Ergo] Goal typed_main_assert_final_c : Timeout
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WP plugin does not support marking properties (preconditions, postconditions, user assertions) as invalid.  As documented in section 2.2 of the [WP plugin manual](http://frama-c.com/download/wp-manual-Sodium-20150201.pdf), the status is one of:

1. [image: never tried icon] — No proof attempted.
2. [image: unknown icon] — The property has not been validated.

   This status means that a proof could not be found.  This might be because the property is actually invalid.
3. [image: valid under hypothesis icon] — The property is valid but has dependencies.

   You will see this status applied to a property if the WP plugin is able to prove the property assuming one or more properties are fully valid.
4. [image: surely valid icon] — The property and all its dependencies are fully valid.

Although the WP plugin does not support marking properties as invalid, you can use the trick of asserting `\false` at the end of the function:

```c
#define L  3
int a[L] = {0};
/*@ requires \valid(a+(0..(L - 1)));
    ensures \forall int j; 0 <= j < L ==> (a[j] == j); */
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    /*@ loop assigns i, a[0..(i-1)];
        loop invariant inv1: 0 <= i <= L;
        loop invariant inv2: \forall int k; 0 <= k < i ==> a[k] == k; 
    */
    while (i < L) {
        a[i] = i;
        i++;
    }
    //@ assert final_progress: \forall int k; 0 < k < L ==> a[k] == a[k-1] + 1;
    //@ assert final_c: a[2] == a[1] - 1;
    //@ assert false: \false;
    return 0;
}
```

Running the WP plugin on this code results in:

```
...
[wp] [Alt-Ergo] Goal typed_main_assert_false : Valid (114ms) (97)
...
```

If the WP plugin marks `assert \false` valid (in the GUI it will show as valid-but-has-dependencies) then you know that there is an invalid property.

Comment: I mark this question as solved but still I do not understand <b>why</b> it is so. After all SMT solver can yield sat/unsat/unknown. Maybe this is because solver has to go through all possible quantified values to claim something as 'invalid', but I doubt that this is practical thing to do.

Comment: @Evgeniy:  You are right that it is possible.  It's just that the WP plugin does not support marking properties as invalid.  The Value Analysis plugin, for example, supports marking properties as invalid.

Comment: @Evgeniy:  Actually, there appears to be a `-wp-unsat-model` option documented in the manual.  However, I get an error when trying that option using Frama-C Sodium:  `[kernel] user error: option \`-wp-unsat-model' is unknown.`

Comment: Looks like it is hidden or not implemented. You wont find it in  $(frama-c -wp-help). As far as I understand from tiny bits of information this option is a hint for underlying SMT solver to generate counterexample when it is unable to discharge logic formula. But if WP does not mark properties as invalid in the first place why it needs such an option then?